# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings' for any django project

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have been studying Django for some time and have been working on a project. Everything was fine until yesterday when I was studying a new topic, saved the project and shut down my PC. There were no errors or anything. Today, when I tried to run my project using the command "py manage.py runserver", I received an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'". I spent enough time trying to solve this problem and assumed that the error was in my project. I couldn't solve it and decided to create a completely new project in a new virtual environment. To my surprise, the same error occurred in this completely new project as well. I thought that I might be doing something wrong, so I repeated the project creation on my laptop, and everything worked as expected with no errors. I tried reinstalling PyCharm and Python, but it didn't help. I don't think I can continue using Django on this PC anymore...

I don't know what data may be needed to solve this problem, so I will provide at least something.
These are the data from the project that was just created.
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coQbe.png)
[Installed modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyCJw.png)
Full error:
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Django2\metanit\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
> main()
> File "C:\Django2\metanit\manage.py", line 18, in main
> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
> File "C:\Django2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
> utility.execute()
> File "C:\Django2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
> self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
> File "C:\Django2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 415, in run_from_argv
> connections.close_all()
> File "C:\Django2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 84, in close_all
> for conn in self.all(initialized_only=True):
>                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Django2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 76, in all
> return [
>            ^
> File "C:\Django2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
> return iter(self.settings)
>                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Django2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
> res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
>                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Django2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 45, in settings
> self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
>                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Django2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
> databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
>                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Django2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
> settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Django2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
> self._setup(name)
> File "C:\Django2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in _setup
> self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Django2\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
> mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\suyar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
> File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings'
```

I thought the error would disappear in the new project, but it remained. I repeated the same steps on my laptop, and everything worked there. Now I think my PC is "broken".

Comment: i think your virtual environment is not set properly

Comment: what should I do to find out my virtual environment settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check that the directory containing the settings module is correctly configured in your project's manage.py file. The manage.py file is the entry point for the Django project and must be correctly configured to launch the project properly.

Comment: manage.py https://prnt.sc/qF3vyk1m03Oe
The project we are reviewing was created automatically with the command 'django-admin startproject metanit', so I believe it should be configured correctly. I haven't made any changes to the project

Comment: check that Django is correctly installed in your virtual environment you can activate your virtual environment and run pip list to see if Django is installed

Comment: I see the list of installed modules in the screenshot provided in the question, but here is the information from the terminal - https://prnt.sc/uLEWg4K5wVFv

Comment: check that your virtual environment is activated while running the project, and also try to run the project with the command python manage.py runserver directly by going into the project directory, instead of using py manage.py runserver.

Comment: Which version your Python btw

Comment: I believe that my virtual environment is active, because I have my environment name written - (venv).
Python version 3.11.2
https://prnt.sc/Cj_N2TdfnyeB

Comment: [this is what I got when I ran the manage.py file](https://prnt.sc/Pde9fyB1U8rf)

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the version of python and django is consistent.

Maybe，it is possible that django is installed in a different location than the python guide package

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how Django and Python versions should match, but here is information about them
django and Interpreter - https://prnt.sc/iIkpIYT7Fv66, https://prnt.sc/mpdFmDiiWX5w

Comment: you could see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django) @ValentinSuyarov

Comment: maybe you could try to set the project directory as sources root, just right click the project directory -> Mark directory as -> sources root @ValentinSuyarov

Comment: I did as you said, the error did not disappear, it seems to me that this is only for visual display - https://prnt.sc/4d_PxAtmrBBL

Comment: Python 3.11.2 , Django 4.1.7, if you look here 
[there](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django), then they compatible as far as I can tell

Comment: what about resynchronize all items, this is the final way

Answer (score -1):

thanks everyone for the help, @Idk's idea - to run manage.py directly led to the message - `Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: No module named 'settings')` after which I found the solution for the first link to google, namely [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE), terminal command - `set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings` solved my problem